# configuring Aptana studio and NetLogo?

Tags: aptana, netlogo

I'm trying to configure aptana to help me code in netlogo, I can't seem to figure out how it's done. Is it a plugin or something?

edit: so bascially how can I import a language into aptana studio?

Comment: Welcome to the site. It's not clear if this question will be answerable in its current state. Can you focus it further?

Answer (score 3):

http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/resources.shtml has an "Editor support" section with plugins for some different programmers' editors including Emacs and Vi. Aptana isn't listed, so that means that so far as we (the developers of NetLogo) know, nobody has done the necessary work to make NetLogo be one of the languages that Aptana supports.

I have no firsthand experience with Aptana, but it seems to be targeted specifically for building web applications. That isn't what NetLogo is for, so it's not surprising that Aptana/NetLogo integration doesn't exist.